# Combining couple of divs in one main wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a series of divs and I am trying to make all of them stay in one main container so they can be moved around as a block. How do I write the CSS to bind all these containers to one single wrapper?
All these series of divs, container, container1, container2 need to be under each other and there are up to 6 of them.

My HTML is:

```
<div id='maincontainer'>
    <div class="photo"><image1.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="title" style="">title</div>
    <div class="desc"><p >You & I </p><p>some text here</p></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn">button</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="btnlink">text</a></div>
</div>

<div id='maincontainer2'>
    <div class="photo"><image1.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="title" style="">title</div>
    <div class="desc"><p >You & I </p><p>some text here</p></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn">button</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="btnlink">text</a></div>
</div>

<div id='maincontainer3'>
    <div class="photo"><image.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="title" style="">title</div>
    <div class="desc"><p >You & I </p><p>some text here</p></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="btn">button</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="btnlink">text</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with putting them all in a wrapper div?

Comment: @Farzin Kanzi. its because each of those containers are different. Container one might have a dimension of say 340x200 and container2 320x100 and the buttons are not all of the same dimension as well. I will have to style each button differently. I was just lazy to specify a class for each button here.. By they way how do you suggest i put them all in one wrapper??..@Farzin Kanzi

Comment: It is not enogh your data you gave us. You can create a fiddle or at least put an image from what you exactly want. Now i do not know why divs are not upon each other, Is it a slider or not ...

Comment: yes i will use them in a slider. so the long vertical blaock conatining couples of divs will be one slide.. Sorry i cannot upload images on here now. i am just new to the site...

Comment: Do you need the container divs have same sizes?

Comment: yes, all the containers  will have the same width of 340px but variable heights.(container1 might be 340x200. container2 340x140 etc etc.... the images with class='photo" will have different sizes as well but i but will all have a  100% height(height of the container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in another div. And just for cleaner code, my recommendation: If you have multiple container, which basically contain the same elements (they hold the same type of information or have the same buildup as in your **maincontainers**), its 'cleaner' to use a class.
If they have to be different from each other then, just add an id.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="maincontainer" id="number1">
        <div class="photo"><image1.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="title" style="">title</div>
        <div class="desc"><p >You & I </p><p>some text here</p></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="btn">button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="btnlink">text</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="maincontainer" id="number2">
        <div class="photo"><image1.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="title" style="">title</div>
        <div class="desc"><p >You & I </p><p>some text here</p></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="btn">button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="btnlink">text</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="maincontainer" id="number3">
        <div class="photo"><image.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="title" style="">title</div>
        <div class="desc"><p >You & I </p><p>some text here</p></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="btn">button</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="btnlink">text</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#wrapper {
    width : 500px; /* or whatever your wrapper's width needs to be */
}

div.maincontainer {
    float : left;
    width : 100%;
}
```

Comment: hi @Tobbe Wilder. Thanks man i think i am getting closer with your suggestion but the problem is that, all those containers  float to the left yes but they align under each other vertically.. Very sure i will need a lot more stylng maybe positioning or and display....

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works perfectly well for me. Just how i wanted, very grateful and keep up the good help..... Thanks a lot...

Comment: @MichelleDimwaite My pleasure. Did you have to adjust the css more or did it work like that? I guess i misunderstood your question (hence your first comment), sorry.

Comment: yeah.. had to adjust the css. still on it at the moment as it involves a lot of moving divs around and me not mastering css and positioning a lot. I might upload a screen shot to a server and show it so you see what i am targeting...

Comment: this is what i am targeting, your suggestions got me on the right path but I still need to fool myself around to get all those divs and buttons around every container. Any help/ will be much appreciated.

Comment: @tobba Wilder this is what i am targeting, your suggestions got me on the right path but I still need to fool myself around to get all those divs and buttons around every container. Any help/ will be much appreciated. http://evebrandt.com/dede.jpg

Comment: Ah ok. Yes this is basically just working with positioning divs inside the wrapper. For that I would recommend you to read those doc articles for better understanding how you can position elements in general:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp
PS: I'm not offended, but please write my name correctly ;)

Comment: <div id="wrapper">
   <div class="container" id="cont1" style="width:300px; height:110px;border:1px solid grey">
      <div class="boxphoto" style="float: right;"><img src="http://image.jpg" style="width:160; height:100%; "/></div>
      <div class="boxtitle" style="color:#800104;font-size:14px">Title</div>
      <div class="boxdesc" style=";margin:0 auto;height:50%; text-align:center; "><p style="color: blue">name</p><p style="font-weight:bold">text</p></div>
      <a href="#" class="btnlink" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;margin-top:-10px;>button</a></div>
   </div>
</div>

Comment: these are codes for one container. even when i copy and past em 3 times. they stick horizontally on the pager. What I my doing wrong?

Comment: You have some typing errors, so the page won't be displayed correct. I loaded the page on my server and corrected the mistakes. Should it look like this?: https://e30i.imgup.net/wrapper75c3.png

Answer (score 0):

I finally had this html for 2 containers for 2 . All i need is to have 4 of them that lines up vertically. under each.
I am not sure whats wrong with the css.
   
      
      Title
      name

text
      button

```
<div class="container" id="cont2" style="width:300px; height:110px;border:1px solid grey">
  <div class="boxphoto" style="float: right;"><img src="http://image.jpg" style="width:160; height:100%; "/></div>
  <div class="boxtitle" style="color:#800104;font-size:14px">Title</div>
  <div class="boxdesc" style=";margin:0 auto;height:50%; text-align:center; "><p style="color: blue">name</p><p style="font-weight:bold">text</p></div>
  <a href="#" class="btnlink" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;margin-top:-10px;>button</a></div>
```

Comment: you have some typing errors in your code.
lookup corrected: https://jsfiddle.net/tobbewidner95/ercLvacL/

Comment: @Tobbe Widner. You are very correct. the image you had is just what I am chasing. Will be more than happy to get that corrected and give myself a nice cup of coffee. brain is shutting down..I rally appreciate you taking time to go through my messy and confused codes.

Comment: Don't worry. Since when are you involved with html/css? I know it's very cliche, but with every minute you work with it, it will become easier.

Comment: @tobbe Widner. Cheer but I have not seen the typing error yet. looking all over the codes, cant seem to find it and i am still on the same messy divs...

Comment: just look at the jsfiddle i sent you in the first comment on this post.
relink: https://jsfiddle.net/tobbewidner95/ercLvacL/

Comment: Got the little stuborn rabbit. Much appreciations @Tobbe Widner.

Comment: Always if you have another question. And if you could vote up my answer, that would make me really happy. But only if I deserve it. That lies in your judgement ;)